# Sorting Complicated Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet of data and I'm not sure the best way to sort it.

It is for an insurance plan. The data includes subscribers, spouses, and children, each with their own row. Each subscriber is given a unique identifier, and there is a column that includes the same unique identifier by row for the subscriber, spouse, and children so that the dependents can be matched up to the subscriber.

I am trying to sort the data by last name so it is alphabetical, but also make sure that if any dependents have different last name, they are still blocked with the subscriber based on the unique identifier. Furthermore, I would like the last "sort" to be the "Relationship" Column, as this identifies Subscriber, Spouse, Child, and I'd like the data to be in that order.

Is this possible for Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data looks like this:

[image]

I suggest adding two helper columns to the worksheet.

- In Cell E1 enter a new column title "IDLast"
- In cell E2 enter the formula `=$C2&$D2`
- In cell F1 enter a new column title "SubscriberName"
- In cell F2 enter the formula `=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($C2&"Subscriber",$E:$E,0))`
- Copy the formulas from E2:F2 to the rest of the rows with data

Column E now contains the ID from this row followed by the relationship.
Column F now contains the last name of the subscriber associated with the person on this row.

This works because `MATCH` will return the row that has **this** row's ID followed by "Subscriber" in column E. `INDEX` will now return the last name from the row identified by `MATCH`.

You can now sort the data first by column F (SubscriberName) in ascending order and then by column D (relationship) in descending order.

[image]

Note that the relationships you mentioned just happens to be in reverse alphabetical order. If there are other relationships that should not appear in that order, you will need a 3rd helper column to translate the relationship into a number that can be sorted on.

If you don't want the helper columns to be visible, you can hide them by selecting the helper columns, right-clicking and choosing "Hide" from the context menu.

[image]

Comment: That solution is exactly what I'm seeking - thank you!!!

Comment: If this solution works for you, please consider marking it as correct with the Check Mark